# We need to Export Data from Joined Report

Tags: joined-reports

We created a Custom Report Type. We need to export data from custom joined report type. Suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Is the printable view button not available (or working in this case?) Is the problem the formatting of the data (i.e. not a CSV file?)

Perhaps if you cleaned it up a bit as described in this article it would provide what you need or at least close to it.

https://cloud62blog.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/exporting-joined-reports-2/ not working?